# Angular Schema Form Custom Template Passing Parameter

Tags: angular-schema-form

I've been searching for a while now and can't find any examples of how I could pass a custom value to a template I created with Schema Form. I needed to create a template to allow for the label to be aligned any way the user wants it to be. I got a simple version of the template working, now I need to give the template information like where the label should be aligned and how many columns the field should take so I can have multiple fields on a single row. I've tried passing my custom fields in the field definition and retrieving it in the template from the form object.

```
firstName = {
    labelAlign: "left"
    title: "First Name"
    type: "string"
}
```

In the sample labelAlign is the custom field that I want to access through the form object and this is part of the data that is passed through the sf-schema directive. Is there another way I can access this data in my template?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

If I pass the custom value in the form JSON instead of the schema JSON the value show on the form but it creates another field at the very end of the form which is not what I am looking for. I've seen schema form examples that show modifying fields in the form JSON without having this problem. Does anyone know how to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question and want to post it here for others. The object I was looking for was form.schema. That will allow access to properties created in the schema JSON.